# Getting base url in PHP

Tags: php

Sorry I moved from PHP CodeIgniter to Pure PHP; I dont know how I can get the base url;

This is what I have attempted:

```
echo($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].":".$_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] .'../template.jpg');
```

the out put is:

```
localhost:8080/my_scheduler/shedule.php../template.jpg
```

What I need is the following:

```
localhost:8080/my_scheduler/template.jpg
```

the following code:

```
$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].":".$_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']
```

gives me the url for current PHP Script I want to go back and get the reqalpath(); but realpath did not work either!

the following code dies not echo anything!

```
 echo realpath($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].":".$_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] .'../template.jpg');
```

Please let me know if you need more clarification!

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`realpath()` works for valid filesystem paths only. There is no ready-made function for this, you'd have to manually cut away the last directory.

If this is for the browser, you *could* just use a relative URL, though:

```
<img src="../template.jpg">
```

Answer (score 1):

my idea 
dispatch your adress with the [parse_url](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) command .
then start and make your true adders with order you like

official example:

```
<?php
$url = 'http://username:password@hostname/path?arg=value#anchor';

print_r(parse_url($url));

echo parse_url($url, PHP_URL_PATH);
?>

Array
(
    [scheme] => http
    [host] => hostname
    [user] => username
    [pass] => password
    [path] => /path
    [query] => arg=value
    [fragment] => anchor
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Usually it is `<?php echo base_url(); ?>` set by most people